# taxonomy template for custom post type the same as the archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

It seems simple but I haven't found an answer....

I have a custom post type 'team' with a taxonomy 'department'

I have an archive page archive-team.php that shows all team posts.

When I need to show a department I want to use the same template, just with the taxonomy as a filter.

But it doesn't*. I could set up a page taxonomy-department.php identical to archive-team.php but this is wasteful and prone to error.

I've looked through the docs and I can't see where you can force the archive type for a taxonomy to go to the archive for that post type.

How?

If it's useful I'll post the functions that created the post type and taxonomy.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/248218/4771).

Comment: Thanks Milo, a bit to get my head around.
-- add a filter for taxonomy_template
-- write a function  to test if  it matches my taxonomy (department)
-- deliver the archive-team template instead.
Watch this space....

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for Milo's pointer

```
function department_template( $template = '' ) {

 if (is_tax('department') ) {
   $template = locate_template( 'archive-team.php' );
 }

 return $template;

}

add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', 'department_template' );
```

Worth noting this doesn't disturb the hierarchy if another taxonomy is involved, ie taxonomy-othertax.php is called correctly for taxonomy 'othertax'.